# WordPress Plugin Boilerplate: Addition of 3rd party scripts and styles

Tags: plugin-development

I am using the [Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) (wppb.io) to build a custom plugin and I am not quite sure where to place a 3rd party script and a 3rd party style for a jQuery Timepicker.

Because the timepicker will be used only in the admin area, is it okay to just place the 3rd party files into the `admin/js` and `admin/css` folders respectively, along with my custom scripts and styles for the admin area?

UPDATE: [According to top contributer of the boilerplate, Tom McFarlin](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/issues/269#issuecomment-75959693) you suppose to place them inside the respective `css` and `js` folders, so I have marked Samuel's answer as correct. Additionally, Tom states that if we are talking about 3rd party libraries, it would be good to create a `lib` subdirectory inside the `css` and `js` folders and place them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMO**, since

> the timepicker will be used only in the admin area

, then YES, it is okay you place the 3rd party files into the `admin/js` and `admin/css` folders respectively.

With that, you *(also other developers)* can be able to clearly know where to find files that corresponds to their respective views.

**Public Folder**: For files that will be used in the frontend

**Admin Folder**: For files that will only be used in the backend.